# Is it possible to show different icons for a react component in Webstorm?

Tags: reactjs, webstorm

Currently all my react components have an icon that looks like all my other javascript files, namely :

[image]

Is it possible to have a different icon if the file is a react component (ie. 'extends Component')

Answer (score 3):

No, the Jetbrains IDEs don't support file icons that way. They just look at the file extension and load the corresponding icon.

However you could name your component files `.jsx` instead of `.js` to have a visual difference between them.

OR

You can use the [Jetbrains API](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html) to write your own extension (naming Icon Provider) which will allow you to select icons based on the content of a file. [Here](https://github.com/joewalnes/idea-community/blob/master/platform/lang-api/src/com/intellij/ide/IconProvider.java) is an example.